# How can I dynamically create grid options for multiple tables using ui-grid in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html5-canvas

I have written one service for ui-grid table. Now I can use this in only one page but, I want to use this service in multiple pages with different table data. How can I pass grid options and json data for multiple tables. How can I do it? Please help anyone.

Service:

```
(function(){
"use strict"; 
angular.module('nApp').controller('SearchResultsController', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', '$interval', 'uiGridConstants', 'uiGridGroupingConstants', function ($scope, $http, $timeout, $interval, uiGridConstants, uiGridGroupingConstants) {
    var searchResults = this;
    searchResults.loadPOHeaderView = loadPOHeaderView;
    //searchResults.loadPOLinesView = loadPOLinesView;

    function loadPOHeaderView() {
        if(dataFactory.getSelectedPOHeader().length) {
            $state.go("^.poheader");
        };
    }

    $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableHorizontalScrollbar : uiGridConstants.scrollbars.NEVER,
    enableVerticalScrollbar   : uiGridConstants.scrollbars.NEVER,
    paginationPageSizes: [25, 50, 75],
    paginationPageSize: 10,
    useExternalPagination: true,
    useExternalSorting: true,
    enableRowSelection: false,
    enableCellSelection: false,
    enableFiltering: false,
    enableCellEdit: false,
    enableColumnResizing: true,
    enableColumnMenus: false,
    enableGridMenu: false,
    showGridFooter: false,
    showColumnFooter: false,
    fastWatch: true,
    enablePaging: true,
    showFilter: true,
    rowHeight: 45,
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        $scope.gridApi.core.on.sortChanged($scope, function(grid, sortColumns) {
            if (sortColumns.length == 0) {
                paginationOptions.sort = null;
            } else {
                paginationOptions.sort = sortColumns[0].sort.direction;
            }
                getPage();
        });
        gridApi.pagination.on.paginationChanged($scope, function (newPage, pageSize) {
            paginationOptions.pageNumber = newPage;
            paginationOptions.pageSize = pageSize;
            getPage();
        });
    },
    columnDefs : [
    { name:'Test1', displayName:'Test1'},
    { name:'Test2', displayName:'Test2'},
    { name:'Test3', displayName:'Test3'},
    { name:'Test4', displayName:'Test4'},
    { name:'Test5', displayName:'Test5'},
    { name:'Test6', displayName:'Test6'},
    { name:'Test7', displayName:'Test7'}     
    ]
    }; 
      var paginationOptions = {
    pageNumber: 1,
    pageSize: 10,
    sort: null
    }; 
      var getPage = function() {
var url;
switch(paginationOptions.sort) {
  case uiGridConstants.ASC:
    url = 'common/service/pogriddata.json';
    break;
  case uiGridConstants.DESC:
    url = 'common/service/pogriddata.json';
    break;
  default:
    url = 'common/service/pogriddata.json?page='+paginationOptions.pageNumber;
    break;
}

$http.get(url)
.success(function (data) {
  $scope.gridOptions.totalItems = 30;
  var firstRow = (paginationOptions.pageNumber - 1) * paginationOptions.pageSize;
  $scope.gridOptions.data = data.slice(firstRow, firstRow + paginationOptions.pageSize);
   }); }; getPage();  }]);})();
```

View page:

```
<div ng-controller="SearchResultsController" class="col-md-12">
<div  ui-grid="gridOptions"  ui-grid-cellNav ui-grid-edit ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-pinning ui-grid-move-columns ui-grid-importer ui-grid-exporter ui-grid-pagination class="grid"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
app.directive('gridWrapper', ['$http',function ($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
  scope:{
   enableFilter:'@',
   enableSorting:'@',
   enableColResize:'@',
   ngModel: '=',
   getHeader: '=',
   getData: '=',
  },
     
        template:'<div ag-grid="gridOptions" class="ag-fresh" id="gridView" ></div>',
  controller:function($scope){ 

          $scope.gridOptions = {
            columnDefs: $scope.getHeader,
            rowSelection: 'single',
            rowData: $scope.getData,
            enableFilter: $scope.enableFilter,
            enableSorting: $scope.enableSorting,
            enableColResize: $scope.enableColResize
          };

  }
    };
  
}]);
```

```html
<grid-Wrapper enable-Filter="{{true}}" enable-Sorting="{{true}}" enable-Col-Resize={{true}}  ng-model="model"   get-header="gridheader" get-data="rowData" ></grid-Wrapper>

<grid-Wrapper enable-Filter="{{false}}" enable-Sorting="{{false}}" enable-Col-Resize={{false}}  ng-model="model1"   get-header="gridheader1" get-data="rowData1" ></grid-Wrapper>
```

Comment: Very Nice but not working.  can u send this as a demo by jsfiddle or plnkr?

Comment: can u share your code what your tried?@Jacob Kristen

Comment: I m using this code into my project so i can not share clearly..also i do not know how to use your code correctly and i do not know how to set json data for table So pls send this one by jsfiddle or plnkr with example table.

Comment: Hi Suresh B...Pls reply

Comment: Update Here: http://plnkr.co/edit/bErmPYo066HSj9Kx4obe?p=preview   @Jacob Kristen

Comment: Don't Forgot Give Tick @Jacob Kristen

Comment: In future if have any query ping me.  @Jacob Kristen

Comment: @SureshB: Do you have any idea to use eternal sorting & pagination, dynamic accordion in wrapper.
I am confuse, how to pass and handle it on directive.

Comment: @SureshB: I am having issue with dynamic drop down creation in above directive, how can I use  array or hash in directive, mean I am creating custom columns which have select box and text box and they are rendering proper but select box doesn't showing the option value.
Prior without directive I was able to assess same.

Comment: Here is plunker link 
http://plnkr.co/edit/lhZQ7D3Y1MWOceXU9J9e?p=preview

Comment: I will check and let you know